# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Even using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am creating a android application.

In my app I have one listView and one gridView and when I set the addapter of those view I get the `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`

I have try to put those setadapter on a AsyncTask but nothing change.. I do not understand.

My Activity :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        showToolbarTitle(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbarTitle.setText("PARALLAX + FADING IMAGEVIEW");
        toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        scrollview.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        new LongOperation().execute(); //I call the AsyncTask

        gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            CustomList adapter = new
                    CustomList(ParallaxLikeIoshedActivity.this, test, imageId, false);
           // listView.setAdapter(adapter); // If I do this I will get the error
            CustomList adapterGrid = new
                    CustomList(ParallaxLikeIoshedActivity.this, test, imageId, true);
          //  gridView.setAdapter(adapterGrid); // If I do this I will get the error
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

This is the layout of the Activity :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <!--<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/moviethumbnail"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />-->
        </FrameLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_below="@id/image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MHeader 1 !!!"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/header"
                android:background="#ff7f7f7f"
                android:showDividers="middle">
                <com.example.edouard.NonScrollListView
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:divider="#000000"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/listview"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <GridView
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:divider="#000000"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/gridView"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: No I am not using an emulator, I am using a Acer A1-713HD Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

Comment: You cannot set adapter on non-ui thread. Do it in onPostExecute.